Dropdown list does not update the selected item immediately React
I use 2 dropdown lists to implement my requirement. I get the data from an endpoint and add 2 items to that data. I will change these data into dropdown lists. When I select the BLEDevice and Camera from dropdown lists, sometimes the value in the component does not change directly. However, it changes the list, which I can see on the logs. How can I solve this issue?
const Dashboard = () => {
    async function getDashboard() {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(BASE_URL + "dashboard");
            const newDevices = res?.data?.devices?.map((device) => ({
                ...device,
                BLEDevice: userModifiedSettings[device.connectionId]?.BLEDevice || "Off",
                Camera: userModifiedSettings[device.connectionId]?.Camera || "Back", // Default to "Back"
            }));
            setDashboardData(newDevices);
            setDashboardLoading(false);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error fetching dashboard:", err);
            setDashboardLoading(false);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getDashboard();
    }, []);

    const toggleDropdown = (connectionId, field) => {
        setDropdownOpen((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [`${connectionId}-${field}`]: !prevState[`${connectionId}-${field}`],
        }));
    };

    const handleDeviceUpdate = (updatedDevice) => {
        setDashboardData((prevState) =>
            prevState.map((device) =>
                device.connectionId === updatedDevice.connectionId
                    ? { ...device, ...updatedDevice }
                    : device
            )
        );
        setUserModifiedSettings((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [updatedDevice.connectionId]: {
                BLEDevice: updatedDevice.BLEDevice,
                Camera: updatedDevice.Camera,
            },
        }));
    };

    const handleSelect = (connectionId, field, value) => {
        const updatedDevice = dashboardData.find((device) => device.connectionId === connectionId);
        updatedDevice[field] = value;
        handleDeviceUpdate({ ...updatedDevice, [field]: value });
    };

    return (
                                            {dashboardData.map((device) => (
                                                <Col key={device.connectionId} sm="6" md="4" lg="3">
                                                    <Card
                                                        className="mb-4 border rounded"
                                                        style={{ borderColor: "#6c757d", borderWidth: "2px", padding: "10px" }}
                                                    >
                                                        <CardBody>
                                                            <CardTitle tag="h5">{device.deviceName}</CardTitle>
                                                            <CardSubtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                                                                Profile:{" "}
                                                                {device.data ? (
                                                                    <FaCheckCircle color="green" />
                                                                ) : (
                                                                    <FaTimesCircle color="red" />
                                                                )}
                                                            </CardSubtitle>
                                                            <CardText>
                                                                <strong>Camera:</strong>
                                                                <Dropdown
                                                                    isOpen={dropdownOpen[`${device.connectionId}-Camera`]}
                                                                    toggle={() => toggleDropdown(device.connectionId, "Camera")}
                                                                    className="d-inline-block ml-2"
                                                                >
                                                                    <DropdownToggle caret color="">
                                                                        <FaCaretDown /> {device.Camera}
                                                                    </DropdownToggle>
                                                                    <DropdownMenu>
                                                                        <DropdownItem
                                                                            onClick={() =>
                                                                                handleSelect(device.connectionId, "Camera", "Back")
                                                                            }
                                                                        >
                                                                            Back
                                                                        </DropdownItem>
                                                                        <DropdownItem
                                                                            onClick={() =>
                                                                                handleSelect(device.connectionId, "Camera", "Front")
                                                                            }
                                                                        >
                                                                            Front
                                                                        </DropdownItem>
                                                                    </DropdownMenu>
                                                                </Dropdown>
                                                                <br />
                                                                <strong>BLE Device:</strong>
                                                                <Dropdown
                                                                    isOpen={dropdownOpen[`${device.connectionId}-BLEDevice`]}
                                                                    toggle={() => toggleDropdown(device.connectionId, "BLEDevice")}
                                                                    className="d-inline-block ml-2"
                                                                >
                                                                    <DropdownToggle caret color="">
                                                                        <FaCaretDown /> {device.BLEDevice}
                                                                    </DropdownToggle>
                                                                    <DropdownMenu>
                                                                        <DropdownItem
                                                                            onClick={() =>
                                                                                handleSelect(device.connectionId, "BLEDevice", "On")
                                                                            }
                                                                        >
                                                                            On
                                                                        </DropdownItem>
                                                                        <DropdownItem
                                                                            onClick={() =>
                                                                                handleSelect(device.connectionId, "BLEDevice", "Off")
                                                                            }
                                                                        >
                                                                            Off
                                                                        </DropdownItem>
                                                                    </DropdownMenu>
                                                                </Dropdown>
                                                            </CardText>
                                                        </CardBody>
                                                    </Card>
                                                </Col>
                                           
    );
};
export default withRouter(Dashboard);



How is dashboardData state declared and what is the initial data in it?

const [dashboardData, setDashboardData] = useState([]);
